# How to sort dataframe where columns are months and rows are years into a single time series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe where the rows are years from 1880 to 2014 and columns are monthly data from january to december.  How do i sort the data such that i have a single time series?  i.e

```
    1880-1 23
    1880-2 66
```

etc...

thanks

originally, my dataframe looked like this:

```
            jan, feb, mar, apl
    1880    23    66...
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us, SO is not a code making place.

Comment: thats the thing.  i have done so much and am confused what to do.  i mean i can go the c++ way and iterate through elements of the dataframe and store and append it to a list.  i was just wondering if there was a more elegant pythonistic way to do this.  i even tried to collapse by dataset but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to convert `jan, feb, mar, ..., dec` to `1, 2, 3, ..., 12`.

```
df.columns = range(1, 13)
```

Now you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[23, 66, 42], [11, 14, 15]], index=[1880, 1881], columns=[1, 2, 3])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       1   2   3
1880  23  66  42
1881  11  14  15

In [13]: df.stack()
Out[13]:
1880  1    23
      2    66
      3    42
1881  1    11
      2    14
      3    15
dtype: int64
```

---

Note: you might prefer a [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range) (rather than a MultiIndex) for later analysis.

```
In [21]: s = df.stack()
         year = s.index.get_level_values(0).values
         month = a.index.get_level_values(1).values

In [22]: pd.PeriodIndex(year=year, month=month, freq='M')
Out[22]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
[1880-01, ..., 1881-03]
Length: 6, Freq: M

In [23]: s.index = pd.PeriodIndex(year=year, month=month, freq='M')

In [24]: s
Out[24]:
1880-01    23
1880-02    66
1880-03    42
1881-01    11
1881-02    14
1881-03    15
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above worked for me, thanks. Two things to note:

typo: month = a.index.get_level_values(1).values

should be: month = s.index.get_level_values(1).values

Also, I had parse_dates=True, so my years were being read in as dates, and then PeriodIndex didn't work. When I left that out, all was well!